# Replace laptop HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I've got a bigger (WD 7500 BPKX Scorpio Black - 750GB) and faster (7200 rpm) HDD for my laptop which has 3200BEVT 320 GB (WD also) 5200 RPM HDD.

I tried to clone the old HDD with mini tool partition wizard but I got an "identical" HDD with 320GB instead of 750GB.

The partition program wouldn't let me use the rest 430 GB.  I guess that the first sectors of the drive determine the usable space.

Is there any way to clone the old HDD but

- (a) be able to use the whole 750GB of the new HDD and
- (b) make all features of the old system usable (working recovery partition etc.)

This is what I get when I use disk management:
[image]

Disk 0 is the old HDD (SATA, internal), disk 1 is a USB stick, disk 2 is a USB icybox with the new HDD inside.

edit: Searching for a solution I came across [this](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Disk-Partioning-and-OneKey-Recovery-Feature/td-p/8034/highlight/false) thread in lenovo support forums which answers the onekey recovery problem. The system partition should not be resized according to them. You need to register if you want to access the thread for more details.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: windows 7 64-bit

Comment: A screenshot of the disk manager showing the new disk would be required to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't post images. Just tell me what info you'd like to see and I'll answer

Comment: You can link to them through a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I can't post images because it's my first question and I have no reputation and also because there is a firewall blocking entrance to media-sharing sites

Comment: You can post a link in the comments.  Without a screenshot I cannot understand at what point the hdd is at.  Figure it out.  The screenshot will be added to your question for you once you post it.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't figure out how to post an image. It just won't let me do it.

Comment: @Ramhound picture posted...

Comment: [How to move windows 7 to a new or larger hard drive using Backup and Restore](http://www.pagestart.com/win7bckuprstrnhd072610.html) covers this for you.  It addresses every step of making the image, imaging the new HDD, and scaling it to the correct size of the new HDD.

Comment: So what's the problem? Does the new drive boot ok? Is the functionality ok? Is it just the size of the partitions that is causing you problems?

Comment: @Zelanix yes the drive booted ok but I had lost almost half the capacity of the new hdd

Comment: @prmths Interesting link, I wonder how I missed it despite googling several times for it! I think it does not address the recovery partition thing because I already have a windows installation disk but that disk wouldn't restore the pc to its original state. I'll try to follow the steps though and inform everybody about the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Western Digital provides something that might help (Acronis True Image for WD)
http://support.wdc.com/product/downloaddetail.asp?swid=119&wdc_lang=en

Depending on your configuration, you could need to download and install the [Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology%20%28Intel%C2%AE%20RST%29)

Comment: I don't need to clone the drive because that's already done... The problem is that I loose a lot of hdd space because after cloning I'm not allowed to resize the partitions and use the unallocated space.

Comment: This will be fixed by this tool! I've successfully cloned a 1TB hdd to a 2TB hdd. You'll be asked to choose between either a proportional cloning or a manual cloning of the existing partitions.

Comment: I hope it will. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried to use true image for wd live cd but after configuring everything I found out that it was just a demo!!! It wouldn't do the actual work. I hope the installed version does. I tried clonezilla instead and it did duplicate my system. Everything worked except the network troubleshooting which refused to work after several attempts. The lenovo recovery also did not work. And I couldn't use the extra 400GB of the new hdd because they were unallocated and unusable (I couldn't create new partitions - no free mbr slots). I'll try with true_image (the installed version) tonight.

Comment: btw crystal mark results were better for the new hdd (although the chipset supports sata 2 only - sata 3 works as a sata 2) by 50% in every category.

Comment: Acronis True Image WD edition (the installed version) copied my disk and took care of the new disk so that every single sector is exploited but as with the other tools that I tried I received error messages when using network troubleshooting. And the one-key recovery process (by lenovo) is not available... :(

Comment: Thanks for your report. The network problem seems to be another issue. Same problem regardless the connection (cable, Wifi, ...)? What are the messages, logs, ... ?

Comment: I don't have any problem with the network itself. But when I do, I can't use troubleshooting which automatically solves 90% of cases. It's the troubleshooting process that's faulty. It returns an error message about the engine. I can't reproduce it right now, so I can't give more details.

Comment: " A problem is preventing the troubleshooter from starting. PackageID=Unknown, Path: C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\networking , Error Code: 0x8E5E0247, Source: Engine, Context: Restricted "

Comment: Error code 0x8E5E0247 seems to be fixed via the Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver: http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4150017&prodNameId=4208009&swEnvOID=4057&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-82337-1 Though I never needed it

Comment: not exactly a perfect solution but this is the best so far...

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you have managed to clone the disk but you want to resize the partitions to make full use of the extra space. For this, I would recommend downloading the [Ubuntu Live DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and using GParted (included on both versions) to resize the partitions as required.

It looks from your screenshot that you will probably want to move the D: partition to the end of the disk and then resize the C: partition.

You can find instructions for this [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd#.UuWe9RDFL0M) among many other places.

Comment: This seems to be the real issue here - you can't resize a drive you're booted into - You need to use an *offline* resizing tool to do this

Comment: I tried GParted but it wouldn't create new partitions. I could only move the unallocated space next to the extended partition and only then it would create a new logical partition but it would tamper with the data stored in the moved partition.

Comment: You need to move the logical partition to the end of the disk, then resize the extended partition to be only as large as the logical partition (leaving the free space next to the primary partition, but not in the extended partition), then expand the primary partition. Does this make sense? It's a bit of a pain and hard to explain, but this really should work.