# Resize Win 7 Partitions, Increase C & Decrease D

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have one 120GB SSD split 40GB/80GB between C & D. I'm trying to increase the size of C to 55GB and decrease D to 65GB. I can only resize D to a lower size, but the unallocated space can only be used to create a different partition after D that is separate from C.

How can I use the unallocated space from D to increase the size of C?

Comment: How are the partitions laid out? If volume C: on a primary partition and volume D: in an extended partition? If that is the case then you need to shrink D away from the place the primary partition is, then reduced the extended partition in size and only then extend the primary one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is do is possible, but time intensive. What will actually happen is the data on D will have to be moved nearer the end of the drive to increase C. You will want to use Easeus Partition Manager from http://litlurl.net/easeus

```
And here's a suggestion to make things go MUCH faster... 

1) move everything from D to an external hard drive, 
2) remove the partition for D drive, 
3) increase C drive, and 
4) recreate D drive.
```

Comment: Very interesting recommendation. Clever way to avoid re-installing windows/programs. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Nickpick: C: and D: are on the same drive, they are different volumes. :)  2) Somewhat more constructive: Speed might not be an issue with a SSD.  3)  Step 2 probaly is "remove the partition for the D: volume **and** remove the extended partition".

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/707390/293259). Personally I don't like the idea of moving the data to another drive in the process; this will essentially just do the same thing anyway, especially when using an SSD and could certainly cause problems if you have applications installed on the D: partition. I prefer to just move it in place (backed up, of course) and let the partitioning software take care of it. But each has their own preference and there is nothing wrong with moving it off as such.

I would recommend downloading the [Ubuntu Live DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and using GParted (included on both versions) to resize the partitions as required.

You will need to resize the D: partition, then move it to the end of the disk and then resize the C: partition. Depending on the partition structure, the D: partition may be a logical partition in an extended partition in which case you will need to resize the extended partition after moving the D: partition before you can resize the C: partition.

You can find instructions for this [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd#.UuWe9RDFL0M) among many other places.